# Not able to execute plugin enable command RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I installed Erlang and RabbitMQ on windows 7. RabbitMQ Service is running. But when I am trying to execute plugin enable command, I am getting below error

```
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 9-Jul-2018::14:14:46.134000 ===
    supervisor: {local,'Elixir.Logger.Supervisor'}
    errorContext: start_error

=INFO REPORT==== 9-Jul-2018::14:14:46.149000 ===
    application: logger
    exited: {{shutdown,
                 {failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler',noproc}},
             {'Elixir.Logger.App',start,[normal,[]]}}
    type: temporary
Could not start application logger: Logger.App.start(:normal, []) returned an er
ror: shutdown: failed to start child: Logger.ErrorHandler
    ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a version of RabbitMQ prior to `3.7.7` with Erlang 21. This is not supported and is clearly documented here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html

Solution: upgrade to RabbitMQ `3.7.7` or downgrade Erlang to version 20.3.

Also, you could have found the answer to this yourself by searching Google with the following text:

```
rabbitmq "Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler"
```